# How to update HTML created with insertAdjacentHTML method based on a select option?

Tags: javascript, html

I am fetching data and then creating an HTML content which is displayed at page start.

I have a select dropdown list with different options that would then sort the array of objects from the API and should then update the HTML content with the new order. Right now I'm getting the sorted array correctly but the HTML content is just being added after the already existing one.

What am I missing or doing wrong?

```js
const container = document.querySelector('.container');
const sort= document.querySelector('.sort');

let url = 'https://mocki.io/v1/11356aa2-6371-41d4-9d49-77a5e9e9924f';

function getTours(option = false) {
  fetch(url)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(out => {
      switch(option) {
        case 'durasc':
          out.sort((a,b) => a.length - b.length)
        break;
        case 'durdesc':
          out.sort((a,b) => b.length - a.length)
        break;
        case 'prasc':
          console.log("Lowest price first");
        break;
        case 'prdesc':
          console.log("Highest price first");
        break;
        default:
          out;
          console.log(option);
      }
    console.log(out);
    out.forEach((el,i) => {
        const cities = el.cities;
        const lastCity = cities.slice(-1)
        const dates = el.dates.map(d => d.start);
        let availableSpaces = el.dates.map(d => d.availability);
        const fromPrice = dates.length!==0 ? Math.min(...el.dates.map(item => item.eur)) : 0;
        const month = ["JAN", "FEB", "MAR", "APR", "MAY", "JUN", "JUL", "AUG", "SEPT", "OCT", "NOV", "DEC"];
        const getDate = function (date) {
          if (date!==undefined) {
            const d = new Date(date)
            const day = d.getDate();
            const name = month[d.getMonth()]
            const year = d.getFullYear()
            const fullDate = `${day} ${name} ${year}`;
            return fullDate;
          } else {
            availableSpaces = ['No', 'No'];
            return 'SOLD OUT!'
          }
        }
        let image = el.images.filter(img => img.is_primary===true);
        image.length>0 && image[0].hasOwnProperty('url') && image[0].url!=='' ? image = image[0].url : image = "https://media.istockphoto.com/id/1357365823/vector/default-image-icon-vector-missing-picture-page-for-website-design-or-mobile-app-no-photo.jpg?s=612x612&w=0&k=20&c=PM_optEhHBTZkuJQLlCjLz-v3zzxp-1mpNQZsdjrbns=";
        const operatorName = el.operator_name;
        const html = `Here is my HTML text`;

        container.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);
    });
    });
  }
    
    
    let listOne = document.getElementsByClassName('sort')
    for (let i = 0; i < listOne.length; i++) {
        let option = listOne[i];
        option.addEventListener('change', () => {
          getTours(option.value);
          return option.value;
        })
    }

getTours();
```

Comment: "...but the HTML content is just being added after the already existing one" - that's what `insertAdjacentHTML` does

Comment: I tried setting the .innerHtml to empty before going through the sorted aray again but I still didn't get the desired result

Answer (score 1):

If i understand correctly you want to:

1. retrieve data
2. sort based on option
3. display sorted data

Step 1 and 2 seem to work but your newly sorted data get's appended to the already existing data?

If that is the case, you never seem to clear your `container` element.

**IMPORTANT** a mistake I usually make is typing `X innerHtml` instead of `innerHTML` <- all caps

```js
console.log(out) // line 26-ish

// clear the container
container.innerHTML = ''

// your out.foreach loop
```

I've included a snippet to show what the change would do, hopefully it's what you're looking for!

```js
const sorted = [1,2,3,4]
const cont = document.querySelector('ul')

const addElements = () => {
  sorted.forEach(e => {
    let html = `<li>${e}</li>`
    cont.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html)
  })
}

const addElementsClean = () => {
  cont.innerHTML = '';
  addElements();
}
```

```html
<button onclick='addElements()'>add w/o clean</button>
<button onclick='addElementsClean()'>add clean</button>

<ul>
<li>dummy</li>
<li>elements</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, you helped me realize my mistake. I didn't want to clear my "container" element because it includes also the dropdown list so I created a special "box" only for the elements from the retrieved data. And on this BOX I should've called the insertAdjacentHTML and clear the same in the eventListener function. After doing this I got it to work. Thanks again for the support!

Comment: Hey man no worries, glad I could help. Maybe in the future also show the HTML code, or at least a simplified version of it. Anyways glad you got it working! PS: when building your HTML elements check out the [createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) works wonders on more complex node structures